# Refresh a TextView from inside a fragment

Tags: android, refresh, fragment

I'm quite new in android and i have a problem trying to develop an app.

I want to make a countdown timer in my activity but i need to do it within a fragment, so i need to put a for loop that count from 0 - 10 and refresh a TextView inside that fragment.

I need the fragment to do it independently from the activity.

thanks for your collaboration

```
public class fragmento_3 extends Fragment {

int count= 10;
TextView texto_count;
View v;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmento_3, container, false);
    texto_count = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.texto_count);
    return v;
}
}
```

and I want to put this inside

```
 for(int x = count; x >= 0 ; x--){
        texto_count.setText(String.valueOf(x));
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

thanks,

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: When i put the for loop inside onCreateView it only shows the last number 0, the textview must show each number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to use `Timer` for periodic tasks rather than using `Thread.sleep`.

Try this code

```
public class fragmento_3 extends Fragment{

    int count= 10;
    TextView texto_count;
    Timer t;
    View v;

    TimerTask timer= new TimerTask(){

        @Override
        public void run() {

            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    count--;
                    if(count >= 0) {
                    texto_count.setText(Integer.toString(count));
                    }
                }
            });
            if (count <= 0) {
                t.cancel();
            }
        }

    };

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmento_3, container, false);
    texto_count = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.texto_count);

    t = new Timer();
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(timer , 0 , 2000);


    return v;
}


}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you, but as I'm new in android, wolud you explain please why it updates the fragment's ui after the return statement?, I understood that once the fragment go over the onCreateView it doesn't update the ui unless it's paused and re drawn.

Comment: `once the fragment go over the onCreateView it doesn't update the ui unless it's paused and re drawn` I don't think so. We can update the fragment UI at any time.

Comment: basically what `Timer` class does is, it creates a new background thread/task independent of main thread which continuously updates/refreshes the textview in the fragment.

Comment: The official documentation for `onCreateView` is : `The system calls this when it's time for the fragment to draw its user interface for the first time. ` For more info you can refer this, http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because you are using the wrong variable `texto_conteo`. You have declared `texto_count` as the instance variable so you probably want to use that.

Comment: sorry, I'm from latin america so I write the code with variables in spanish, when i posted the question i changed all names but as i can see i forgot one, sorry

Comment: Have you tried using `Thread.sleep` for a longer period than 100?

Comment: yes, but i've got the same result, it only shows the last number I also tried to put the for loop inside the onResume method of the fragment but I have the same result

Comment: Try using a `CountdownTimer` with the length of 1000 and `onTick` of 100

Comment: ok, but where do i put that inside? because the problem is more in the fragment lifecycle

Comment: You should put it in `onResume`